# Power shell script which silently installs softwares

Tags: powershell, installation, automation

```
    # Source file location
$source1 ="https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/11.0/win32/enUS/Firefox%20Setup%2011.0.exe"
$source2 ="https://www.fosshub.com/Code-Blocks.html?dwl=codeblocks-20.03-setup.exe"
$source3 ="https://github.com/x64dbg/x64dbg/releases/download/snapshot/snapshot_2021-07-01_23-17.zip"
$source4 ="https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.9.6/python-3.9.6-amd64.exe"
$source5 ="https://www.nasm.us/pub/nasm/releasebuilds/2.15.05/win64/nasm-2.15.05-installer-x64.exe"

# Destination to save the file
    $destination1 = "C:\Users\cdac\Desktop\Shravan\Softwares\firefox.exe"
    $destination2 = "C:\Users\cdac\Desktop\Shravan\Softwares\codeblocks.exe"
    $destination3 = "C:\Users\cdac\Desktop\Shravan\softwares\xdbg.zip"
    $destination4 = "C:\Users\cdac\Desktop\Shravan\softwares\python.exe"
    $destination5 = "C:\Users\cdac\Desktop\Shravan\softwares\nasm.exe"


    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $source1 -OutFile  $destination1
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $source2 -OutFile  $destination2
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $source3 -OutFile  $destination3
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $source4 -OutFile  $destination4
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $source5 -OutFile  $destination5

 #Installing one software

    Start-Process -Wait -FilePath 'C:\Users\cdac\Desktop\Shravan\Softwares\codeblocks.exe' -ArgumentList '/silent' -PassThru
```

I have written Powershell script which downloads the software tools from the internet through URL and stored in a separate directory but iam not able to install all the softwares which are stored in a separate directory silently using foreach loop. kindly help me in writing script for installing all the softwares stored in a directory using foreach loop.

Thanking you

Comment: Which part is your problem, the loop or the silent installation?

Comment: You need to research how each installer can be installed silently, i.e.: for firefox you can use msiexec, for python I think the installer already has a `/quiet` switch > `python-3.9.x-amd64.exe /quiet`

Comment: You could look at Chocolatey packages to see how _they_ silently run each installer in the install script. It's Powershell too. (There is also WinGet but in my experience it's often not silent.)

Comment: But probably the best way would be for you to look for MSI packages which are designed to be auto-installed, often vendors provide them (for enterprise scenarios).

Comment: You may take a look at the [Windows Package Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/package-manager/)

Answer (score 1):

There isn't enough information to say exactly what's going wrong here - what error are you getting specifically? What behavior are you observing when you run your script? My first guess is that your foreach loop is running through installer *names*, not the full path like you posted in your example.

That said, if I understand what you're trying to do, here's a quick and dirty way to do what I think you're after;

```
# Array of installer details
[Hashtable[]]$Installers = @();
# Firefox
$Installers += @{
    SoftwareName = "Firefox"
    Url = "https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/11.0/win32/enUS/Firefox%20Setup%2011.0.exe"
    Destination = "C:\Users\cdac\Desktop\Shravan\Softwares\firefox.exe"
    Arguments = '/s'
}
#Code Blocks
$Installers += @{
    SoftwareName = "CodeBlocks"
    Url = "https://www.fosshub.com/Code-Blocks.html?dwl=codeblocks-20.03-setup.exe"
    Destination = "C:\Users\cdac\Desktop\Shravan\Softwares\codeblocks.exe"
    Arguments = '/silent'
}

function Install-Software([Hashtable]$installer) {
    Write-Host "Installing $($installer.SoftwareName)"
    Write-Host "Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $($installer.Url) -OutFile $($installer.Destination)"
    Write-Host "Start-Process -FilePath $($installer.Destination) -ArgumentList $($installer.Arguments) -Wait"
    
    # Remove Write Host above - uncomment the following lines:
    #Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $installer.Url -OutFile $installer.Destination
    #Start-Process -FilePath $installer.Destination -ArgumentList $installer.Arguments -Wait
}

foreach($installer in $Installers) {
    Install-Software -installer $installer
}
```

I'd recommend having a look at the [PSAppDeployToolkit](https://psappdeploytoolkit.com/) if you're trying to package applications silently using PowerShell - this helped me a lot back when I was doing a lot of SCCM packaging.

Comment: When I included the above code in my script. It is giving the following details in the terminal window Installing Firefox
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/11.0/win32/enUS/Firefox%20Setup%2011.0.exe -OutFile C:\Users\cdac\Desktop\Shravan\Softwares\firefox.exe
Start-Process -FilePath C:\Users\cdac\Desktop\Shravan\Softwares\firefox.exe -ArgumentList /s -Wait

Comment: @ShravanMeghavath - # is the comment syntax in PowerShell. Read this comment in the above code; `#Remove Write Host above - uncomment the following lines:`

Comment: Thanks sir, Firefox is installed but code blocks is not installing I am getting the following error message. I am attaching the error message please help me sir.

Comment: Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable. At C:\Users\cdac\Desktop\Shravan\script_2.ps1:85 char:5

Comment: I've edited the code above - in the `hashtable` for each piece of software there's an argument list as well - I left `/s`  as the silent install for codeblocks, but looks like you were using `/silent` instead. Try replacing the silent install arguments in the hashtable with the correct one (although, I'd be surprised if this was the reason).

This error sounds more like the file didn't download correctly - what happens when you try run the `exe`  manually? If it works when double clicking the `exe`, then try updating the install arguments.